# Usage of Knockout in a Polymer Component raises error: "Uncaught Error: You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element."

Tags: html, knockout.js, binding, polymer

I've this Polymer Component:

```
<dom-module id="visu-conveyor">
    <template>
        <div id='conveyor' style="background: lightblue; height: 100%; width: 100%">
            {{objectName}}
            <div style="width: 80px; height: 90%; background-image: url(images/rollers_horizontal.png); background-repeat: repeat;">
                <div style="width: 10px; height: 10px; background: blue;" data-bind="visible: A_B_A"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </template>

    <script>
    Polymer({
        is: "visu-conveyor",
        properties: {
            objectName: String
        },
        ready: function () {
            var self = this;
            var viewport = self.$.conveyor;

            ko.applyBindings(visuClient_Tags, self.$.viewport);
        }
    });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

When I use this multiple times, I got this error! But I think the Element to which I apply the Binding is every time another one (A instance of the temple)? Or I'm wrong?

Comment: I'm no expert in polymer, but the name of the DOM element variable is "`viewport`": I'd expect both polymer components to be housed in the same virtual viewport, thus explaining the error you're getting. - Isn't there some property on `self.$` that holds a reference to the *component*'s DOM element?

Comment: ??? I've multiple instances of my custom element in the same container! and their dom should be used in knockout!

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to convey with the abundance of interpunction? I was just trying to place a helpful comment... In any case, I do understand that you have multiple instances of the component, but doesn't `viewport` always refer to the *same* DOM element that contains all those instances of your own component? What happens if you `console.log(self.$.viewport)` just before `applyBindings`? I'd hazard a guess it's the same element multiple times over. (But again: I don't know polymer very well.)

Comment: My Example Code was wrong... I've fixed it! Sorry for that! But still the same error!

Comment: No sorry, you were correct! my Code was wrong, now the error is gone

Comment: Please consider rolling back the last edit to your question, and instead post it as an answer. This makes it easier for others with the same problem to spot.

Answer (score 0):

Was a typo error!

my code should look like this:

```
<script>
Polymer({
    is: "visu-conveyor",
    properties: {
        objectName: String
    },
    ready: function () {
        var self = this;
        ko.applyBindings(visuClient_Tags, self.$.conveyor);
    }
});
</script>
```